# Error starting program installed on a remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a program that is installed on the server, that all users are running directly from the server. This program has run for quite some time, but now it has suddenly started to fail on startup.

The program still starts as normal from the server, and if I copy the files directly to the users machine it also works fine.

The application uses EntityFramework to access a database that is residing on another server. All machines mentioned are located on the same network.

When starting the application on the client, I get the following error message:

[image]

It looks like some sort of permission problem, but I can't seem to figure out what. Hope someone can put on on the right path to understanding this problem.

**EDIT**

Since you can't zoom on image, here is the first part of the error message:

SystemTypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException> An error occred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework> Attempt by method 'System.Configuration-TypeUtil.CreateInstanceRestricted(System.Type, System.Type)' to access method 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.DefaultConnectionFactoryElement..ctor()' failed.

Comment: The first few lines of message text would be helpful.  There's no good way to zoom the image.  I see something about ConfigurationErrorException, but can't read the rest.

Comment: You probably already have tried but... Have you run the application under elevated privileges? I deduce that you are executing it on Windows 8 machine.

Comment: if you just zoom in on the whole page (ctrl+) the picture is readable.  Or right click, open in new tab

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy - Added the start of the error message as text in case youstill can't read it.

Comment: @HuorSwords - I tried to rightclick and choose to run as administrator if that is what you are thinking about.

Comment: Possibly a missing assembly for a custom configuration section?

Comment: Something must have changed.. did you upgrade Entity Framework? upgrade .NET? different OS? changes to the configuration file?

Comment: @TimB - Something must have changed, but not with the files in the application directory, OS or anything obvious. The only thing I know about was that the server booted due to windows updated sometime yesterday, and I don't know if it ever worked since that. But at least it fails every single time now.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy - Then why should it matter if I run the files from the server (mapped up as a network drive), or from my local machines (the exact same files copied from the server).

Comment: By default, .NET applications running from a network share run in partial trust. That appears to be what is causing the error to me. I don't know why it would work before and not now though.

Comment: Good point.  And some of that stack trace is Security exceptions.  @TimB raises a good question.  What changed?

Comment: You could try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem is EF related. I had a similar problem as result of Microsoft's July Patch ([KB2840628](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840628)). A solution is the installation of [KB2872041](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872041).

Another solution is the update to Framework 4.5.

Comment: That was it! Now it works as it used to again. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciated :)